# Get Post / Page URL - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, post

I have the following code

```
<div id="featured-posts" class="container_12">
<?php
 global $post;
 $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&category=12');
 foreach($myposts as $post) :
 ?>

 <?php global $post; ?>
    <?php
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
    ?>

        <?php
            $colors = array("#000000", "#949c51", "#571c1e", "#f36533", "#782a80", "#f6a41d", "#ed1b24");
            $randomColor = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
        ?>

<a href="LINK OF THE POST"><div class="grid_4 featured-home" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;">
    <div class="featured-details" style="border-color: <?php echo $randomColor; ?>;">   
        <h2 style="color: <?php echo $randomColor; ?>;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="featured-lower" style="border-color: <?php echo $randomColor; ?>;"></div>
</div></a>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

This takes the most recent 3 posts, in category 12 and displays them in a div. I want this whole div to link to the post. You'll see where it says **LINK OF THE POST**. Can anyone help me get the URL in here?

Thanks
dvent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpress provides a method for that : the_permalink();

Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop.

You can also use the get_permalink($id) method.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink